# Cpu clock Frequence can be 0?

Tags: android, cpu-usage, ddms, systrace

I am tracing my Android system in sleep mode (screen off) by using Systrace in Ddms. In systrace's graph, i saw sometime CPU frequency is 0. So, I want to ask, Can CPU frequency is 0?

Comment: Did it *start* at zero or *drop* to zero?  Generally speaking, systrace records *changes* in frequencies, so if the frequency never changes you might never see an actual value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can, without the CPU being able to truly sleep we would be charging our phones 10 times a day.

Keeping it short, CPU sleeps when it has nothing to do, and wakes up using special hardware mechanisms in different systems (Radio/AlarmManager/Buttons/Etc..)

Comment: But when Using showfreq tool for android, it shows at least the Minimum frequency set for that Cpu. Do you know that tool?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that tool. What is the output of it?

Comment: The cpu when not asleep has a range of frequencies to save power when there is no need for full processing power, so its probably showing it. But I cant be sure.